# How to load axios data as initial redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I try to load some axios json result on my initial state in order to open my app with a prepopulated state but i do not manage to load the axios result in my that initial state, i can see it on my console but the return doesnt work here

this is the code of my reducer

```
import axios from "axios";


const getBookings = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/bookings.json')
      .then(res => resolve(res.data))
  });
}


const getInitiatState = getBookings().then(
  function(data)
  {
    console.log(data)
    const initialState = {
      data: data, // ' ' or axios result
    };
    return initialState;
  }

)


function bookings(state = getInitiatState, action)
{
  switch(action.type)
  {
    default:

      return state

  }

}

export default bookings;
```

Comment: You should make it as empty array/object and "initialize" state later with proper action.

Comment: What Fard said. I normally do this step in a component did mount on the index of the application, or somewhere early on in your app.

Comment: Also the issue is that you are actually adding the promise to the state initally. You will see the data eventually, but after the promise object gets added to your initial state.  Remember JS is synchronous but AJAX is asynchronous. Javascript will not wait for the ajax to finish (maybe an implimentation if async await could work?)

Answer (score 2):

As i said in comments: You should make it as empty array/object and "initialize" state later with proper action. Right now instead of making state with array you fill it with promise.

My sample using React with hooks and `setTimeout` (this will work the same with your fetch): https://codesandbox.io/s/6wwy4xxwwr?fontsize=14

You can also just do it in your "`index.js`" using `store.dispatch(action)` like:

```
import store from './fileWithConstStore';

fetch()
.then(data => {
  store.dispatch({
    type: 'INIT_BOOKINGS',
    payload: data 
  })
});
```

but this rather quick than approved solution.